# sudo for specific commands without password doesn't work

Tags: permissions, sudo

I really tried to find a solution before posting here, however I couldn't find any.

I tried to allow a specific user to run `apt update` and `apt upgrade` for a without entering his password, so I did a `sudo visudo` and edited the line for this user:

```
user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt update /usr/bin/apt upgrade
```

sudo -l gives me the following output:

```
User user may run the following commands on machine:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt update /usr/bin/apt upgrade
```

What am I missing? Just allow ALL is no option. The order should be fine. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: you might use `username ALL = NOPASSWD : /usr/bin/apt-get , /usr/bin/aptitude` the update/upgrade & so on parameters is on the command line `sudo aptitude update` for example   ; not in the sudoers file.

Comment: @ShahFahad quoting them does not work. throwing syntax errors.

Comment: @francoisP So there is no way to limit commands? I don't want to allow the whole apt for security reasons

Comment: Did you try putting a comma between the commands in the `sudoers` file? I can't see how `sudo` would otherwise be able to determine that the list of words are two separate commands with arguments.

Comment: @Kusalananda wow, yeah. thats how to solve. Thank you!

Comment: just a note that giving a user unrestricted `apt install` rights is the same as giving them unrestricted rights to execute anything; once you can `apt install` stuff as root, it's your machine. From a usability/operational safety point of view, still a better idea to only give yourself unprotected access to `apt install`, because it's highly unlikely you'll damage something accidentally that way. the trick of gaining root is simply to make a debian package and install it [locally using `apt install ./package.deb`](https://superuser.com/a/1244531/563936).

Comment: @MarcusMüller thats why I just wanted update & upgrade :)

Comment: @moTHO. uuuuh `apt update -o "Dir::Etc::sourcelist=/path/to/your/sources.list"` allows you to specify that you have package repository of your own, and that might contain conveniently updated packages that contain arbitrary things you put in there

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think sudo would ask for a password if any other arguments are given

Comment: ah, true, @rowboat!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The separate commands needs to be separated by a comma in the `sudoers` file, e.g.

```
user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt update , /usr/bin/apt upgrade
```